# RhinoMocks Error "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement"

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

```
var CoreDataManagerMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<ICoreDataManager>();
CoreDataManagerMock.Stub(r => r.LoadTranQuotesThatNeedBasicRates).Return(new List<int>());
CoreDataManagerMock.Stub(r => r.LoadTranQuotesThatNeedCompoundRates).Return(new List<int>());
CoreDataManagerMock.Stub(r => r.LoadTranQuotesThatNeedResetRates).Return(new List<int>());
```

So I want to set this up so that those three calls on the mock object return `new List<int>()`, but I get this compiler error:

```
Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
```

Am I setting this up wrong? The actual methods return type `List<int>`.

Comment: @George - I think adding RhinoMocks to the title would make it even more searchable, but fee free to rollback if you disagree

Comment: @Adam I don't disagree, but my original title was over 150 characters.

Comment: @George - I don't follow.  Is being > 150 characters good?

Comment: @Adam no, there's a 150 character limit, and I didn't have a good googeable title that included the error message and a narrative way of including RhinoMocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since these are methods, you need parenthesis when setting up the Stub:

```
CoreDataManagerMock.Stub(r => r.LoadTranQuotesThatNeedBasicRates())
                   .Return(new List<int>());
```

Comment: Oh man, knew my first post 3k rep dumb moment would come soon enough. THanks Adam.

Comment: @slandau - no problem!  Just be aware that the dumb moments don't stop when you hit 10K, and even 20K :)